# Populate an existing object with JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I populate a class using Json.Net like this:

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(result.ToString());
```

The result JSON string above populates a couple of properties in my `Account` class.  I later have a new JSON string and want to populate the same `Account` class with the remaining properties.  Is this possible using JSON.NET or a `JsonConvert` method? I basically want to append/add to the account object I've populated in the line of code above.

My class:

```
public class Account
{
    public string CID { get; set; }            
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> mail { get; set; }
    public List<string> uid { get; set; }
    public List<string> userPassword { get; set; }            
}
```

Comment: You know ahead of time which properties will be populated the first and second times?

Comment: yes.  the first 3 properties will be populated first then the last 3.

Comment: So sounds like it would be pretty simple to just manually hardcode that. Like `MyObject.mail = NewObject.mail; MyObject.mail = NewObject.uid; MyObject.userPassword = NewObject.userPassword;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm) to fill in properties on an existing object from a second JSON string.

Here is an example:

```
string json1 = @"
{
    ""CID"": ""13579"",
    ""jsonrpc"": ""something"",
    ""id"": ""24680""
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json1);

string json2 = @"
{
    ""mail"": [ ""abc@example.com"", ""def@example.org"" ],
    ""uid"": [ ""87654"", ""192834"" ],
    ""userPassword"": [ ""superSecret"", ""letMeInNow!"" ]
}";

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json2, account);

Console.WriteLine("CID: " + account.CID);
Console.WriteLine("jsonrpc: " + account.jsonrpc);
Console.WriteLine("id: " + account.id);
Console.WriteLine("mail: " + string.Join(", ", account.mail));
Console.WriteLine("uid: " + string.Join(", ", account.uid));
Console.WriteLine("userPassword: " + string.Join(", ", account.userPassword));
```

Output:

```
CID: 13579
jsonrpc: something
id: 24680
mail: abc@example.com, def@example.org
uid: 87654, 192834
userPassword: superSecret, letMeInNow!
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/621bfV