# How can I replace just the property that comes with json dynamically?

Tags: c#, oop, mvvm, properties

I want to update an existing object from json, but the problem is, the json string comes from a AWS iot core and gives just the property that changed.
For example, this is the class:

```
public class Data
{
    public float Temperature { get; set; }

    public float Humidity { get; set; }

    public float Pressure { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have an instance of that class, e.g:

```
var current = new Data { Temperature = 25, Humidity = 60, Pressure = 990 };
```

Now the mqtt event gets triggered and brings this json:

```
{"Temperature":20}
```

When I call

```
current = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonString);
```

Then Temperature is 20, but Humidity and Pressure is 0, because it gets overwritten.

How I can achieve that just the value existing in the json code gets changed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This can be solved in many ways. How exactly do you intend to use 'current'?

Comment: Untested, but this post seems like the thing you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138228/populate-an-existing-object-with-json

Comment: Thank you @RazorShorts, "PopulateObject" was what I was looking for.